# Plotting column values on condition of other columns of dataframe using matplotlib against same x-axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with 600 rows in the shape of :

```
rpttime         metric          value
25/4/2018 15:45 UTIL_CPU        1.5
25/4/2018 15:44 IDLE            74
25/4/2018 15:41 REC_BYTES_S     0
25/4/2018 15:47 ENT_CPU         100
25/4/2018 15:44 ENT_CORE        1
25/4/2018 15:48 TRANS_BYTES     92
25/4/2018 15:43 PINNED          5425
25/4/2018 15:48 PAGING_PAG      0
25/4/2018 15:48 IOPS_IN         NULL
25/4/2018 15:47 TRANS_BYTES_S   23484
25/4/2018 15:43 PAGE_OUT        0
25/4/2018 15:42 IOPS_OUT        10
```

I want to plot line plots for the "value" column on y-axis against "rpttime" on x-axis as time-series for each individual items in the column "metric". There are around 20 individual items in the column "metric". There are some NULL values in the "value" column which are to be omitted which is the row is to omitted for each NULL value in the "value" column. There are atleast one NULL value for each individual items of the "metric" column. All line plots for those 20 individual items are to plotted in one graph. How to approach this ?

Comment: Can you post a clean data frame with which rows with value==Null, as it's ambiguous from the posted data frame due to both NA and numerical values present?

Comment: Updated the dataframe. The NULL value appears at least once for each individual items of the "metric" column.

Comment: So do you want to ignore the `rpttime` where `value`==Null while ploting series? Or fill it with some other value?

Comment: Ignore the whole row, wherever value==Null.

Comment: rpttime contain string like 25/4/2018 15:48 and the dataframe has an index column starting from 0 which isn't shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want separate lines plotted for each `metric`-value, you first should `groupby` metric:

```
grpd = df.groupby('metric')
```

Then you can iterate over the created groups plotting each set of values against `rpttime`:

```
for name, data in grpd:
    plt.plot(data.rpttime.values, data.value.values, 'x-', label = name)
plt.legend()
```

Note: data you provided is not enough for a really impressive result though, as there are not multiple equals in metric:

[image]

PS: imported your data with

```
df = pd.read_fwf('wherever/file/may/roam', colspecs=[(None, 15), (16, 31), (32, None)])
df.rpttime = pd.to_datetime(df.rpttime)
```

PPS: `NA` is handeled automatically, i.e.: NULL-values just are not plotted (see `IOPS_IN`)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use df.dropna() to drop `Null` values which aren't desired while plotting

```
import pandas as pd

# Original data frame
>>>df_origin
```

[image: Original dataframe with Null values]

```
# Drop NaN values using dropna
df_to_be_plotted = df_origin.dropna()
>>> df_to_be_plotted
```

[image]

Comment: Dropping NULL values is ok, any solution on plotting multiple time-series data of column "value" with individual items of "metric" column.

Comment: I guess you can take a view from original data frame for each unique item in `metric` column to plot a time series against values in `value` column. If you can elaborate more on plotting part in question it'll be helpful